# Cypress Code coverage for component testing

Tags: cypress

We have component tests written in cypress.
We've instrumented the code successfully but cypress is not executing the instrumented code for component tests.

How do we get Cypress in component mode to execute instrumented code?

Comment: Hey Cypress, this would be very useful to be able to do!